# Why does MSVC optimize away this memcpy call?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following C code (I shortened it removing some other calls and checks):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory.h>

extern char buffer[];

extern void getstr1(char *buff, int buflen);
extern void getstr2(char **s);
extern void dosomething(char *s);

void myfn()
{
    char *s, *s1;
    int len;

    getstr1(buffer, 128);
    getstr2(&s);

    len = *s + *buffer;
    memcpy(buffer + *buffer + 1, s + 1, (*s) * sizeof(char));
    *buffer = len;

    dosomething(buffer);
}
```

MSVC with the /O2 optimization option produces the following output:

```
_s$ = -4                                                ; size = 4
void myfn(void) PROC                                 ; myfn, COMDAT
        push    ecx
        push    128                           ; 00000080H
        push    OFFSET char * buffer             ; buffer
        call    void getstr1(char *,int)           ; getstr1
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR _s$[esp+12]
        push    eax
        call    void getstr2(char * *)                    ; getstr2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _s$[esp+16]
        push    OFFSET char * buffer             ; buffer
        mov     al, BYTE PTR [eax]
        add     BYTE PTR char * buffer, al
        call    void dosomething(char *)              ; dosomething
        add     esp, 20                             ; 00000014H
        ret     0
void myfn(void) ENDP                                 ; myfn
```

You can check this [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m9yH0C)

Why did the compiler omit the memcpy call? It's interesting that declaring the external variable as "extern char buffer[N];" where N >= 2 or as "extern char *buffer;" makes the compiler use memcpy. Also replacing memcpy with memmove does the same thing. I know about possible UB when the source and destination regions overlap but here the compiler doesn't have knowledge of this.

Comment: Is `extern char buffer[];` legal?

Comment: @NathanOliver AFAIK it's more or less the same as `extern char *buffer;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky At least not exactly the same, sizeof() for example doesn't work on the former case

Comment: @Ctx right, but with either case `sizeof buffer` doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: Is this producing the expected results?

Comment: Are you compiling it as C or C++? Keep the tag for the language used, remove the other.

Comment: It could be that `extern char buffer[];` is not legal in msvc indeed (it is hard to tell when it comes to this compiler).. When adding some explicit size to it, the `memcpy` is coming back. For standard C it is just declaring an array of incomplete type.

Comment: I tried both C and C++: the result is the same. Initially it was C code. More details: the issue can be reproduced with MSVC 2005 and with modern compilers too (some of them you can check on godbolt.org).

Comment: @Jabberwocky That was just a hint, that it is _not_ the same, but an entirely different type (array of unspecified number of char vs. pointer.) together with an example, where this difference can come into play.

Comment: Well, C or C++ matters because C++ has a standard header called `memory` but C has no such thing, apart from I believe some non-standard Linux header. Maybe there's also some MS trash called memory.h? I can't find it in MSDN. What I'm getting at is that you haven't included `string.h` which is required for memcpy. VS, being barely compliant with C90 at best, might then go bananas and assume the prototype is `int memcpy(int, int, int);` because they probably don't follow C99 either. It's really hard to guess what this so-called "compiler" does and doesn't.

Comment: well the answer is in "N >= 2 or as "extern char *buffer;" makes the compiler using memcpy". The compiler thinks the buffer is of size 0, and omits the seemingly redundant memcpy.

Comment: @Lundin: Changing `<memory.h>` to `<string.h>` produces the same results.

Comment: @Ctx Yes, as I wrote, using pointer instead of array does the trick. But in fact it looks like optimizer treats external array variable of unknown size as an array of zero size.

Comment: Changing `memcpy` to `(&memcpy)` results in the compiler including the `memcpy` call in the generated assembly. This could be used to demonstrate that the behavior with and without `memcpy` differs, which could be used to demonstrate this is the result of a compiler bug.

Comment: @oleque Yes, that's my impression, too.

Comment: `extern char buffer[];` is ***legal***. Additionally it is ***nothing like `extern char *buffer;`***.

Comment: interestingly enough, if you declare "extern void memcpy1(unsigned char *a,unsigned char *, unsigned int);" and use it for memcpy it gets included now... https://godbolt.org/z/DFoJjn

Comment: If the declaration is changed to `buffer[1024]` or `buffer[2]`, the compiler includes `memcpy`. If you change it to `buffer[1]`, the compiler does not. So it is not just the compiler treating `extern unsigned char buffer[];` as if `buffer` had a size of zero.

Comment: @Lundin MSDN 2005 says that memcpy requires for <memory.h> or <string.h>

Comment: If, in the destination of `memcpy`, `buffer + *buffer + 1`, the `1` is changed to `2` (without any of my other changes mentioned above), the compiler does generate the `memcpy`. This is quite looking like a compiler bug.

Comment: Interestingly, `buffer + *buffer - 1` generates the `memcpy`, but `buffer + *buffer + -1` does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil please see the answer with the link.

Comment: oleque , What is the _definition_ of `buffer[]` (from some other .c file)?  IMO, if that is a `char *buffer;` or `char buffer[same_constant];` makes a difference.

Comment: @chux It doesn't matter because the call is excluded even from single compiled file (without any other info about the buffer). In real code, of course, it defined like "char buffer[some_constant];"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a bug in MSVC as what you are doing is legal.

Note that there has been a similar bug filed already titled: [Release build with speed optimize leaves an array uninitialized](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/333884/release-build-with-speed-optimize-leaves-an-array.html).

The code given to reproduce the problem in the bug report also uses an `extern type array[];`

As per the team, this issue is fixed in an upcoming release (which is not mentioned).

Comment: ... "nice"... and the "interrim stopgap fix" is to modify all C source code.

Comment: Seems unlikely that they had this bug for 12 years without anyone noticing though?

Comment: @Lundin Or.. they don't care?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same bug but they wrote VS2015 produced correct output. On godbolt site you can try both of them and result is the same (memcpy call missing).

Comment: ***fixed in an upcoming release*** Not sure if that means VS2019 or one of the VS2017 releases. I would not expect any older compiler to be fixed.

Comment: Well, it really looks like MSVC bug. The workaround is to specify extern array sizes, e.g.: "extern char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];"

Answer (score 2):

What you do is perfectly legal, this is definitely a bug in MSVC.

Here is a stripped down version to file a bug report:

```
#include <string.h>

extern unsigned char buffer[], *s;

void myfn() {
    memcpy(buffer + *buffer + 1, s + 1, *s);
    *buffer = 1;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
void myfn(void) PROC                                 ; myfn, COMDAT
        mov     BYTE PTR unsigned char * buffer, 1
        ret     0
void myfn(void) ENDP                                 ; myfn
```

Removing the statement `*buffer = 1;` prevents the code generation bug.
Check it on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eVJjRv).